# Why is the canonical parameter linearly related to the input x in GLMs and why does it give the link function?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, generalized-linear-model, exponential-family, link-function

In Andrew Ng's CS229 notes, one of the three assumptions he makes for constructing GLM models is:

> The natural parameter $\eta$ and the inputs x are related linearly: $\eta=\theta^Tx$

He goes on to say that:

> The third of these assumptions [assumption above] might seem the least well justified of the above, and it might be better thought of as a “design choice” in our recipe for designing GLMs, rather than as an assumption per se.

So for example, when formulating $y|x;\theta \sim Bernoulli(\phi)$ as $y|x;\theta \sim ExponentialFamily(y;\eta)$ we get:

$$\eta=log\left(\frac\phi{1-\phi}\right)$$
$$E\left[y|x;\theta\right]=\phi=\frac1{1+e^\eta}$$

What is the intuition of this design choice? And why does the canonical parameter $\eta$ correspond to the link function that makes the distribution parameter map out to $\theta^Tx$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$